# Consulta SQL para borrar registro relacionado con varias tablas y foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 4 tablas tal que así

```
create table bolis (
  id int primary key,
  marca varchar(20)
  );
create table lapices (
  id int primary key,
  marca varchar(20)
  );
create table gomas (
  id int primary key,
  marca varchar(20)
  );
create table estuche (
  id int primary key,
  id_boli int,
  id_lapiz int,
  id_goma int,
  descrip varchar(20),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_boli) REFERENCES bolis(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_lapiz) REFERENCES lapices(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_goma) REFERENCES gomas(id)
  );
  
  insert into bolis values (1, 'aaa');
  insert into bolis values (2, 'bbb');
  
  insert into lapices values (1, 'aaa');
  insert into lapices values (2, 'ccc');
  
  insert into gomas values (1, 'aaa');
  insert into gomas values (2, 'ddd');
  
  insert into estuche values (1, 1, 2, 1, 'estuche 1');
  insert into estuche values (2, 2, 2, 2, 'estuche 2');
  insert into estuche values (3, 2, 1, 1, 'estuche 3');
  insert into estuche values (4, 2, 2, 1, 'estuche 4');
```

Y tengo que borrar todos los bolis cuya marca sea coincida con la marca de gomas o lapices

Sé que es muy básico el ejemplo pero es lo que me piden, y no estoy seguro de si mi consulta está bien:

Mi consulta es esta:

```
DELETE FROM bolis WHERE marca IN (select distinct(marca) from lapices) and marca in (select distinct(marca) from gomas);
```

Pero me da que no es todo lo óptima que podría ser ya que tiene 2 subconsultas y eso a la hora de la verdad podría ralentizar la BD.

A parte de que existen registros en estuches que podrían contener esos bolis y creo que la consulta que he escrito daría error por conflicto de foreign key.

He podido usar esta herramiento para hacer pruebas:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Pero no consigo sacar la solución limpia de esto.

Actualización, es posible que esto sea correcto?

```
SET @marcas = 'SELECT b.marca FROM bolis b
INNER JOIN lapices l on l.marca = b.marca
INNER JOIN gomas g on g.marca = b.marca';

SET @NODEL = 'SELECT distinct(b.marca) FROM estuche e 
             INNER JOIN bolis b ON b.id = e.id_boli';

DELETE FROM bolis WHERE marca in (@marcas) AND marca NOT IN (@NODEL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu distinct sobra y además ahí te borrará las que estén en las 3 y tú necesitas que coincida con una o con otra, no hace falta las 2.

DELETE FROM bolis WHERE marca IN(
SELECT bo.marca
FROM bolis bo, lapices la, gomas go
WHERE bo.marca=la.marca
OR bo.marca=go.marca);